# python - Create variables in loop then assign

Tags: python, excel, loops, variables, openpyxl

I'm trying to create variables inside a loop, then assign a value to them in the same loop iteration.  My code is failing, I can see why, but cannot figure out how to fix it.  I'm using Python 3.6 with current versions of all imported packages.  Here's my code:

```
import openpyxl

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

for month in months:
    filepath = 'C:\codes\Furnace_time_log\\2019\\' + month + '_2019.xlsx'
    workbook_name = month+'_wb'
    workbook_name =  openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet_name = month+'_sheet'
    sheet_name = workbook_name.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

What I want out of this is 12 openpyxl sheet objects named "January_sheet", "February_sheet", ...

Earlier in my code I have the following sample which does exactly what it's supposed to.  This is what I'm basing the logic of my erroneous code on:

```
head_wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\codes\Furnace_time_log\head.xlsx')
head_sheet = head_wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet 1')
```

I'm working with an Excel file where every row contains a date and a lot of other useful information.  If row x's date is in January, I need to place the adjacent data in a separate XLSX document ("January_2019.xlsx"), which I can edit via the January_sheet object.

Any advice on how accomplish this?  Also, I am not concerned with performance.  This code only has to run once on the full data set.  I realize there's probably a more efficient way of doing this than concurrently opening 12 openpyxl workbooks and sheets.  That being said, any better ways of accomplishing this are welcome.

Comment: Usually, it would help to present the error message and the place the code fails.

Comment: See this question for lots of options, such as dictionary, namedtuple, etc: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Comment: 1. There is only one Excel file with `Sheet 1`.  2. You want to create multiple files, based on the date in a column of `Sheet 1`.  Please confirm.  Also, post the header and top 5 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your interface at all, but this is what I've gathered:

```py
import openpyxl

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

sheets = {}

for month in months:
    filepath = 'C:\\codes\\Furnace_time_log\\2019\\' + month + '_2019.xlsx'
    workbook =  openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet_name = month + '_sheet'
    sheet = workbook_name.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
    sheets[month] = sheet
```

This is assuming that your sheets are named `xxxx_month`(e.g. `January_month`, case-sensitive) and not `Sheet1` as you were originally using. When this is done you'll have a dictionary mapping month name to sheet object.

Let me know if something I've done doesn't make sense and I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you, this did exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I can see several problems with your code:

1. Improper escape sequence in the file name.
2. Reassigning variables.
3. You are trying to create two different sets of dynamic variables: workbooks and sheets, without establishing relation between them.

In the code below, the first line stores value to variable 'sheet_name'. The second stores new value into same variable changing its value:

```
sheet_name = month+'_sheet'
sheet_name = workbook_name.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

What you are trying to do is to dynamically create a variable name and value. Unless there is an overwhelming need to create such set of variables, I would recommend using either list or dictionary for this:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March','April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 
          'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
wb_format = r'C:\codes\Furnace_time_log\2019\{}_2019.xlsx'
workbooks = dict((month, wb_format.format(month)) for month in months)
```

If you really want to create those variables, look up [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals), but do use caution.